# How to update the state of an object in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

My question might sound stupid but I swear my brain freeze, I google it for answer but honestly I don't even know what should I search for. So basically I have a reducer, usually when I'm using redux I'm using arrays and my reducers look like this:

```
import { FETCH_ALL, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE } from '../constants/actionTypes';

export default (posts = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_ALL:
      return action.payload;
    case CREATE:
        return [...posts, action.payload];
    case UPDATE:
        return posts.map((post) => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post);
    case DELETE:
        return posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload);
    default:
      return posts;
  }
};
```

And now I only have an object, and I really don't know what to write on case UPDATE, I mean I'm not looping through and find my updated object and that process.
My question is how can I update if I only have an object

```
import { FETCH_PROFILE, UPDATE_PROFILE } from '../constants';

export default (profile= {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PROFILE:
      return action.payload;
    case UPDATE_PROFILE:
      return ;
    default:
      return profile;
  }
};
```

like here, in that case UPDATE_PROFILE, what should I write to make it work, in my backend everything going well, the return is an object with the updated user.
I know my question is stupid, but please be kind! Thank you in advance

```
    Unexpected token, expected "," (8:32)

   6 |       return action.payload;
   7 |     case UPDATE_PROFILE:
>  8 |       return {...profile, action.payload};
     |                                 ^
   9 |     default:
  10 |       return profile;
  11 |   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For object you will use spread operator just like in an array:**

```
import { FETCH_PROFILE, UPDATE_PROFILE } from '../constants';

export default (profile= {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PROFILE:
      return action.payload;
    case UPDATE_PROFILE:
      return {...profile, action.payload};
    default:
      return profile;
  }
};
```

More about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

Comment: Did it help you?

Comment: it's saying ' expected  ', ' ', idk why the syntax is correct

Comment: it must be { ...profile, profile: action.payload } and the error dissapear, i'm checking if it's working

Comment: Yeah, it depends on your payload object schema.

Comment: In database it's modified, but I have to reload the page to see changes, so I guess it's not working

Answer (score 0):

**In your update profile, pass the entire object after updating.**

For eg:

```
let profiles =[{name:"foo",id:1},{name:"bar",id:2},{name:"baz",id:3}]
    
let updateProfile = [{id:2,name:"gaurav"}]
then, first update the profiles with updated profile, that is, 
    
const updatedProfiles = profiles.map(item=>item.id===?:updatedProfile:item)
```

then, simply pass updatedProfiles in action.payload,

in your reducer, it will be then

```
case UPDATE_PROFILE:
     return  action.payload;
```

Comment: I understand, I was just wanting if I only have one object to use one object not to use arrays, but if that's the only way I can accomplish that, thank you very much